# Getting always NULL in Cart Item GetPrice() function

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart, quote

I'm manually adding some products to the cart:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(113);
$params = array(
  'product' => 113,
  'qty' => 1
);
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($params);
$cartHelper->getCart()->addProduct($product, $request);
```

But the price is always empty (or null).

I've been debugging the execution through

```
Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart->addProduct(...)
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProduct(...)
Mage_Sales_Model_Quote->addProductAdvanced(...)
```

and finally:

```
protected function _addCatalogProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $qty = 1)
{
    $newItem = false;
    $item = $this->getItemByProduct($product);
    if (!$item) {
        $item = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item');
        $item->setQuote($this);
        if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin()) {
            $item->setStoreId($this->getStore()->getId());
        }
        else {
            $item->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        }
        $newItem = true;
    }

    /**
     * We can't modify existing child items
     */
    if ($item->getId() && $product->getParentProductId()) {
        return $item;
    }

    $item->setOptions($product->getCustomOptions())
        ->setProduct($product);

    // Add only item that is not in quote already (there can be other new or already saved item
    if ($newItem) {
        $this->addItem($item);
    }

    return $item;
}
```

But the price is not there, in that $item :(

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The price in a quote item is set in `\Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::collectTotals`

So you need to run `\Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::collectTotals` to have a price, this happens when a page is rendered, after reload.

You can run this manually, but be careful, unfortunately the method stores a bunch of cached prices, which may be reused in a wrong way and might lead to wrong prices if called twice!

Answer (score 0):

Along with the suggested below `collectTotals()` call please try to set store id to the product before load.

`$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($storeId)
            ->load(113);`